# Remove HTML Tags from API response

Tags: json, flutter, api

may i know how to remove html tags form my data fetched from api..right now it shows like the pic below

[image: Here]

my api fetch is like this

```
    fetchNews() async {
        setWordsState(WordsState.LOADING);
      
        final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(ApiUtil.WordFetch));
        data = json.decode(response.body);
        WordList wordslist = new WordList.fromJson(data["word"]);
        allwords = wordslist.words;
    
        setWordsState(WordsState.LOADED);
      }
```

Do let me know if i am unclear please as i will try to provide more things to clear your doubt to understand my question.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to fetch? is it all the text in the list item? "Hello:Ni sa bula or just bula (ni sahm boo-lah)" ?  Also not sure if you will have more than one <li> tag? Also specify what language you are using javascript+jquery?

Comment: Please share your json response body as Text

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it got solved as I surrounded the data in my page by Generator element

`Generator.parseHtmlString(allwords[1].name)`

Thanks